# create child objects if they don't exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example I have object:

```
person = {
            Name: 'John',
            Address: {
               Name: 'NY'
            }
         }
```

and I have array of properties:

```
0: Name,
1: Address.Name,
2: Car.Name
```

I want to create all properties(object) if they don't exist. For example above, I want to get:

```
 {
       Name: 'John',
       Address: {
          Name: 'NY'
       },
       Car: {
          Name: null
      }
 }
```

PS. The array is dynamically builded. I don't know which properties there are.

Comment: TIP - You have a typo: `Addess`.

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat: I use kendo grid and oData. When I describe kendo model, I write `Address.Name`, but if this property is null on server, then it won't be in json result. Therefore, when grid is rendered, I get  error `Address.Name is undefined`. And I want to add this properties to json response.

Comment: I expect the 'array of properties' is somehow generic, is not always the same, right?

Comment: @fast: Yes, you are right.

Comment: In what format do you have this array of properties (list of strings?)? In what language/where (server/client) do you want to extend the original object?

Comment: This array contains list of strings. Actually, I have another object which is used for building this array. Client is javascript, server is `asp.net webapi2 odata`. I want to extend on JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add missing properties, you can iterate through the properties, check if it is present in the object and add as required.

```
// original object
var person = {
    Name: 'John',
    Address: {
        Name: 'NY'
    }
};

// list of all properties
var props = ['Name', 'Address.Name', 'Car.Name'];

// iterate through the properties and add as needed
props.forEach(function(prop) {
    var root = person;
    prop = prop.split('.'); // split by . to use [] notation subsequently
    for(var i=0; i<prop.length; i++) {
        if(typeof root[prop[i]] === 'undefined') root[prop[i]] = (i === prop.length-1 ? null : {});
        root = root[prop[i]];
    }
});

console.log(person);
/*
{
    Name: 'John',
    Address: {
        Name: 'NY'
    },
    Car: {
        Name: null
    }
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first create an object with all the properties set to null, and then use [$.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) to merge them together.

```
obj = {
       Name: null,
       Addess: {
          Name: null
       },
       Car: {
          Name: null
      }
 };
person = {
       Name: 'John',
       Addess: {
          Name: 'NY'
       }
};
person = $.extend(true,obj,person);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why you need that but as i understand its useless.

If you need that to validate if value is set you can do simply

```
var result = (person.Address && person.Address.Name) //true will be returned if address and address name are not null and defined.
```

Answer (score 0):

If particular property is not yet created typeof will return undefined . you can make use of that to create new property.

```
if(typeof Car.Name === "undefined")
Car.Name = null; //initialize to some value
```

Comment: Thanks. Butl look at PS section, please. I don't know what properties in the array and in the object, it's generic.